# How to find the number of files in a jar file

Tags: java, metrics

I'm a beginner in java and this is not actually a program question, but I would like to get some advice from you guys on how to get the number of files in a `.jar` java file? Is there any metric tools that I can use for this (consider its a .jar file)?

Comment: Can you open it in winzip?

Comment: @IanO'Brien  Yes, I can open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `.jar` files are just `.zip` files, you can use the same tools to work with them. On *nix, if you want to list all of the files in a JAR:

```sh
$ unzip -l filename.jar
```

Will produce output similar to the following:

```
Archive:  filename.jar
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
     1211  03-03-14 13:06   bar/foo/swing/window/FrameOperatorFactory.class
     2344  03-03-14 13:06   bar/foo/swing/window/FrameOperator.class
     1509  06-30-07 14:03   LICENSE.txt
 --------                   -------
  5184390                   3 files
```

(The above output is only an example.)

If you want just `*.class` files:

```sh
$ unzip -l filename.jar | grep \.class | wc -l
```

If you want more control, you're likely better off just unzipping it and working with the files that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use a zip tool (with caveats, see below) or `jar`. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29):

> In software, JAR (Java ARchive) is a package file format typically used to aggregate many Java class files and associated metadata and resources (text, images, etc.) into one file to distribute application software or libraries on the Java platform.[3]
>
> JAR files are fundamental archive files, built on the ZIP file format and have the .jar file extension. Computer users can create or extract JAR files using the jar command that comes with a JDK. They can also use zip tools to do so; however, the order of entries in the zip file headers is important when compressing, as the manifest often needs to be first. Inside a JAR, file names are unicode text.[4]

Comment: I mean the number of class files only. Not the entire files in the jar file.

Comment: I used SONARQUBE for finding out the number of files, classes, lines of codes in .zip file. But I can't use the same tool for .jar file. Is there any other way I can get to know these metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command for find the number of class in specific jar file

```
jar tvf {jar location with jar name} | grep .class | wc -l
```

For Example :

```
jar tvf launcher/target/user.jar | grep .class | wc -l
```